# Android Things Raspberry pi 3 jack 3.5mm not working

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I implemented an application run on Raspberry pi 3 using Android Things. This application be able to play `rtsp` video and out put to screen via HDMI port. But the audio is not working with jack 3.5mm. Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Did you know there's whole Stack Exchange site for the Raspberry Pi? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you using DP6?

Comment: @NickFelker What is DP6?

Comment: @NickFelker Yes I'm using Developer Preview 6

Comment: Okay I think using HDMI out will by default take priority for audio over the headphone jack.

Comment: @NickFelker So how can I use both HDMI and jack? HDMI for video and jack for audio.

Comment: There's a method you can use for an `AudioTrack`, `setPreferredSource` but I'm unsure how it applies to video players.

Comment: @NickFelker Could you please give me an example how to use them?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to work for video playback

Comment: @NickFelker OK I got it thank you.